# Python Tkinter commands priority

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have faced a strange problem in my program.

```
from tkinter import *
import time 


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Test')
        self.root.geometry('400x500')
        self.root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
        self.root.configure(bg ='#1A181B')

    def draw_widgets(self):
        Button(self.root, text='Start', font='Verdana 17',command = self.start_bot).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def run(self):
        self.draw_widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_bot(self):
        Button(self.root, text='Start', font='Verdana 17', command=self.start_bot).grid(row=2, column=1)
        time.sleep(4)
        print('a')


win = Window()
win.run()
win.draw_widgets()
```

As you can see after pressing a button, I want to create another button, then wait for 4 seconds, then print 'a', but it is doing another thing: 1) Waiting for 4 seconds 2) Printing 'a' 3) Creating button.

Please, how I can fix this, I really need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `time.sleep()` the application suspends processing until the time period is done. This includes updating the GUI changes. To allow the changes to take effect before sleep is started you have to tell the application to do that with `update_idletasks()`. See example:

```
def start_bot(self):
    Button(self.root, text='Start', font='Verdana 17',
           command=self.start_bot).grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.root.update_idletasks()    # Update GUI changes
    time.sleep(4)
    print('a')
```

Have a look at the `after()` function, which does not suspend processing but schedules something for a later time. This may often be a good function to use instead of sleep.